# Random horizontal line showing in d3 line chart?

Tags: d3.js

I'm plotting data as a line chart and for some reason there are random horizontal lines going across one part of the graph:

[image: chart]

I'm plotting my data like this:

```
const timeConv = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f");
const width = 960;
const height = 500;
const margin = 5;
const padding = 5;
const adj = 30;

/* adding svg */
const svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
    .attr("viewBox", "-"
          + adj + " -"
          + adj + " "
          + (width + adj * 3) + " "
          + (height + adj * 3))
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .style("padding", padding)
    .style("margin", margin)

/* sanitizing data */
const dataset = d3.json("formattedStats.json")
dataset.then(function(data) {
/* scaling */
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, d => timeConv(d.dateCreated)));
    yScale.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, d => d.balance)
    ]);

    const yaxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .ticks(20)
        .scale(yScale);

    const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(d => d3.timeDay.count(0, d) % 3 === 0))
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d'))
        .scale(xScale);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xaxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
        .call(yaxis);


    const line = d3.line()
        .x((d) => xScale(timeConv(d.dateCreated)))
        .y((d) => yScale(d.balance));

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("stroke", "black")

});
```

And my data looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "balance":1433,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T19:03:38.627"
   },
   {
      "balance":1426,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T19:01:50.766"
   },
   {
      "balance":1449,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:58:56.856"
   },
   {
      "balance":1465,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:45:02.957"
   },
   {
      "balance":1476,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:38:27.707"
   },
   {
      "balance":1483,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:09:21.723"
   },
   {
      "balance":1489,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:07:10.662"
   },
   {
      "balance":1506,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:07:01.501"
   },
   {
      "balance":1515,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T04:06:49.871"
   },
   {
      "balance":1531,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T03:47:41.251"
   },
   {
      "balance":1542,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T03:04:08.571"
   },
   {
      "balance":1558,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:27:07.284"
   },
   {
      "balance":1575,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:21:03.609"
   },
   {
      "balance":1591,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:14:47.54"
   },
   {
      "balance":1596,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:13:51.064"
   },
   {
      "balance":1612,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:13:35.578"
   },
   {
      "balance":1620,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T01:49:01.64"
   },
   {
      "balance":1606,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T01:05:31.986"
   },
   {
      "balance":1639,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T00:13:31.93"
   },
   {
      "balance":1656,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-23T00:05:29.045"
   },
   {
      "balance":1672,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T23:53:33.355"
   },
   {
      "balance":1679,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T23:45:19.324"
   },
   {
      "balance":1702,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T08:06:04.961"
   },
   {
      "balance":1709,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T07:41:31.159"
   },
   {
      "balance":949,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T06:11:06.519"
   },
   {
      "balance":915,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T04:11:45.495"
   },
   {
      "balance":932,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T03:31:21.528"
   },
   {
      "balance":981,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T02:09:29.896"
   },
   {
      "balance":965,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-22T02:08:44.348"
   },
   {
      "balance":859,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T23:16:21.725"
   },
   {
      "balance":837,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T22:11:51.734"
   },
   {
      "balance":853,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T21:51:33.269"
   },
   {
      "balance":869,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T21:25:00.833"
   },
   {
      "balance":862,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T21:17:35.604"
   },
   {
      "balance":839,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T20:30:21.715"
   },
   {
      "balance":856,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T07:51:15.532"
   },
   {
      "balance":899,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T07:10:07.262"
   },
   {
      "balance":915,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T05:37:19.123"
   },
   {
      "balance":910,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T05:33:59.065"
   },
   {
      "balance":883,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T05:24:11.467"
   },
   {
      "balance":871,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T03:21:38.474"
   },
   {
      "balance":888,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T03:10:32.186"
   },
   {
      "balance":891,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T03:05:09.042"
   },
   {
      "balance":861,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T02:05:56.146"
   },
   {
      "balance":878,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T01:43:27.761"
   },
   {
      "balance":901,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-21T01:34:25.554"
   },
   {
      "balance":907,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T23:18:39.558"
   },
   {
      "balance":924,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T22:59:25.504"
   },
   {
      "balance":940,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T21:01:51.96"
   },
   {
      "balance":879,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T20:48:54.406"
   },
   {
      "balance":857,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T19:56:13.648"
   },
   {
      "balance":890,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T19:50:26.716"
   },
   {
      "balance":906,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T19:00:18.921"
   },
   {
      "balance":882,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T07:46:33.574"
   },
   {
      "balance":896,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T07:07:40.55"
   },
   {
      "balance":879,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T07:04:25.858"
   },
   {
      "balance":906,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:52:07.748"
   },
   {
      "balance":922,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:42:51.575"
   },
   {
      "balance":927,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:42:31.973"
   },
   {
      "balance":934.26,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:16:09.036"
   },
   {
      "balance":902,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T05:31:56.692"
   },
   {
      "balance":923,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T05:31:47.108"
   },
   {
      "balance":894,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T05:22:20.871"
   },
   {
      "balance":867,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T04:00:32.576"
   },
   {
      "balance":883,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T04:00:26.06"
   },
   {
      "balance":900,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T02:14:11.529"
   },
   {
      "balance":916,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T01:38:55.908"
   },
   {
      "balance":933,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T01:23:53.772"
   },
   {
      "balance":949,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-20T01:23:45.458"
   },
   {
      "balance":956,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:33:45.224"
   },
   {
      "balance":962,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:08:56.22"
   },
   {
      "balance":979,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:08:38.623"
   },
   {
      "balance":880,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:06:48.195"
   },
   {
      "balance":894,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T22:12:00.778"
   },
   {
      "balance":877,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:57:13.62"
   },
   {
      "balance":910,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:33:02.45"
   },
   {
      "balance":925,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:25:22.116"
   },
   {
      "balance":949,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:20:51.796"
   },
   {
      "balance":965,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T20:59:27.897"
   },
   {
      "balance":982,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T07:47:45.451"
   },
   {
      "balance":822,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T07:44:31.419"
   },
   {
      "balance":879,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T07:34:22.508"
   },
   {
      "balance":797,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:46:47.993"
   },
   {
      "balance":814,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:46:07.785"
   },
   {
      "balance":820,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:36:24.427"
   },
   {
      "balance":827,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:20:59.223"
   },
   {
      "balance":861,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:19:46.962"
   },
   {
      "balance":823,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:08:21.955"
   },
   {
      "balance":840,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:07:30.056"
   },
   {
      "balance":851,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:05:20.705"
   },
   {
      "balance":849,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:39:32.269"
   },
   {
      "balance":866.29,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:26:06.534"
   },
   {
      "balance":825,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:13:44.842"
   },
   {
      "balance":836,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:11:43.612"
   },
   {
      "balance":852,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:04:52.876"
   },
   {
      "balance":858,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:04:27.291"
   },
   {
      "balance":874.54,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:04:12.409"
   },
   {
      "balance":843,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:57:22.911"
   },
   {
      "balance":859,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:52:21.601"
   },
   {
      "balance":875.24,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:50:29"
   },
   {
      "balance":847,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:45:57.354"
   },
   {
      "balance":880,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:28:35.598"
   },
   {
      "balance":897,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:17:26.469"
   },
   {
      "balance":913,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-18T07:16:47.016"
   },
   {
      "balance":947,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-18T06:37:00.094"
   },
   {
      "balance":930,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-18T06:31:42.495"
   },
   {
      "balance":952,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-17T09:08:22.177"
   },
   {
      "balance":939.94,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-17T08:49:21.978"
   },
   {
      "balance":918,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-17T08:34:31.417"
   },
   {
      "balance":929,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-17T08:34:01.094"
   },
   {
      "balance":935,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-16T07:08:20.004"
   },
   {
      "balance":951,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-16T07:07:46.132"
   },
   {
      "balance":968,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-14T04:39:32.887"
   },
   {
      "balance":984,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-14T04:39:15.779"
   },
   {
      "balance":1000,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-14T02:03:00.87"
   },
   {
      "balance":1017,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-14T01:31:32.207"
   },
   {
      "balance":1033,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-14T01:31:19.978"
   },
   {
      "balance":1040,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T23:23:29.921"
   },
   {
      "balance":1095.59,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T23:18:21.912"
   },
   {
      "balance":1072,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T22:37:24.883"
   },
   {
      "balance":1088,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T21:00:57.88"
   },
   {
      "balance":1091,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T20:10:58.344"
   },
   {
      "balance":1093.04,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T20:10:39.9"
   },
   {
      "balance":1055,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T19:20:51.553"
   },
   {
      "balance":1071,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T19:09:34.993"
   },
   {
      "balance":1071,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T19:09:12.291"
   },
   {
      "balance":1088.47,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T08:34:06.731"
   },
   {
      "balance":1020.97,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T08:24:09.093"
   },
   {
      "balance":999,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T08:12:13.226"
   },
   {
      "balance":1015,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T07:49:26.818"
   },
   {
      "balance":1032,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-13T07:40:00.178"
   },
   {
      "balance":1114,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T23:23:32.335"
   },
   {
      "balance":1154,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T21:01:59.128"
   },
   {
      "balance":1169.97,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T14:39:57.463"
   },
   {
      "balance":1156,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T14:01:02.792"
   },
   {
      "balance":1172,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T13:55:36.566"
   },
   {
      "balance":1177,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T13:55:19.394"
   },
   {
      "balance":1156,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T08:24:33.968"
   },
   {
      "balance":1121,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T08:08:41.735"
   },
   {
      "balance":1089,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T06:48:28.84"
   },
   {
      "balance":1106,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-12T05:40:55.865"
   },
   {
      "balance":1036,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T22:45:14.995"
   },
   {
      "balance":1012,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T21:52:56.498"
   },
   {
      "balance":1028,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T21:36:53.419"
   },
   {
      "balance":1043,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T09:20:19.116"
   },
   {
      "balance":1037,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:27:01.816"
   },
   {
      "balance":1043,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:26:45.696"
   },
   {
      "balance":1066,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:26:30.808"
   },
   {
      "balance":1070,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:08:32.191"
   },
   {
      "balance":1081.18,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:04:44.88"
   },
   {
      "balance":1049,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T06:59:57.157"
   },
   {
      "balance":1066,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T06:29:55.306"
   },
   {
      "balance":1082,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-11T06:29:37.378"
   },
   {
      "balance":1089,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T07:20:38.373"
   },
   {
      "balance":1120,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T07:04:02.663"
   },
   {
      "balance":1131,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T07:02:00.364"
   },
   {
      "balance":1148,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T05:50:07.739"
   },
   {
      "balance":1164,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T05:24:33.478"
   },
   {
      "balance":1108,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T05:23:31.012"
   },
   {
      "balance":1083,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T04:10:02.153"
   },
   {
      "balance":1099,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T04:09:37.055"
   },
   {
      "balance":1114,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T02:40:05.837"
   },
   {
      "balance":1095,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T02:13:02.745"
   },
   {
      "balance":1106.16,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T02:10:33.916668"
   },
   {
      "balance":1108,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:43:12.406"
   },
   {
      "balance":1092,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:39:59.102"
   },
   {
      "balance":1113,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:35:38.467"
   },
   {
      "balance":1087,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:14:38.311"
   },
   {
      "balance":1103,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T00:50:09.294"
   },
   {
      "balance":1153,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T00:35:48.635"
   },
   {
      "balance":1136,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-10T00:13:15.698"
   },
   {
      "balance":1169,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T23:42:45.742"
   },
   {
      "balance":1180,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T23:41:51.207"
   },
   {
      "balance":1186,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T20:29:33.056"
   },
   {
      "balance":1219,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T19:34:09.69"
   },
   {
      "balance":1235,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T19:18:24.581"
   },
   {
      "balance":1236,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T19:11:14.349"
   },
   {
      "balance":1252,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T17:13:40.924"
   },
   {
      "balance":1268,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-09T06:47:22.183"
   },
   {
      "balance":1284,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T17:42:38.056"
   },
   {
      "balance":1301,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T17:42:28.833"
   },
   {
      "balance":1306.58,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:49:25.341"
   },
   {
      "balance":1285.58,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:32:08.722"
   },
   {
      "balance":1275,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:29:17.285"
   },
   {
      "balance":1282,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:29:09.891"
   },
   {
      "balance":1285,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:22:57.768"
   },
   {
      "balance":1290,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:20:55.432"
   },
   {
      "balance":1294,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T07:06:29.286"
   },
   {
      "balance":1300,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T06:47:13.151"
   },
   {
      "balance":1291,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T06:44:23.775"
   },
   {
      "balance":1270,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T05:46:22.013"
   },
   {
      "balance":1287,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-08T05:45:47.899"
   },
   {
      "balance":1149,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-07T11:19:38.463"
   },
   {
      "balance":1129.93,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-07T08:29:41.744"
   },
   {
      "balance":1107,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-07T07:48:21.005"
   },
   {
      "balance":1116,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-07T07:48:04.45"
   },
   {
      "balance":1134,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-07T06:07:27.17"
   },
   {
      "balance":1101,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T18:13:04.993"
   },
   {
      "balance":1075,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T16:50:49.551"
   },
   {
      "balance":1098,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T16:41:05.869"
   },
   {
      "balance":1105,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T04:53:57.638"
   },
   {
      "balance":1121,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T04:53:47.715"
   },
   {
      "balance":1128,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T03:52:28.386"
   },
   {
      "balance":1194,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T03:33:55.42"
   },
   {
      "balance":1177,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T03:19:55.119"
   },
   {
      "balance":1210,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:53:50.235"
   },
   {
      "balance":1227,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:40:53.788"
   },
   {
      "balance":1243,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:40:39.762"
   },
   {
      "balance":1252,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:19:43.451"
   },
   {
      "balance":1269,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-05T21:41:31.196"
   },
   {
      "balance":1275,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-05T21:34:16.157"
   },
   {
      "balance":1219,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-05T19:53:26.309"
   },
   {
      "balance":1192,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-05T19:04:36.269"
   },
   {
      "balance":1198,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-05T19:04:10.751"
   },
   {
      "balance":1249,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-04T05:38:08.098"
   },
   {
      "balance":1228,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-04T05:23:06.225"
   },
   {
      "balance":1271,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-04T03:26:17.131"
   },
   {
      "balance":1304,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-04T03:12:01.939"
   },
   {
      "balance":1327,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-04T03:09:45.315"
   },
   {
      "balance":1334,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-04T02:45:19.182"
   },
   {
      "balance":1343,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-03T20:49:14.146"
   },
   {
      "balance":1353.8,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-03T08:00:24.059"
   },
   {
      "balance":1290,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-03T07:39:10.192"
   },
   {
      "balance":1322,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-03T07:28:01.269"
   },
   {
      "balance":1322.65,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-02T08:16:47.869"
   },
   {
      "balance":1287,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-02T06:46:09.676"
   },
   {
      "balance":1304,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-02T06:40:26.221"
   },
   {
      "balance":1310,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-02T06:30:15.057"
   },
   {
      "balance":1328,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-01T06:40:06.844"
   },
   {
      "balance":1345,
      "dateCreated":"2020-07-01T06:23:22.739"
   },
   {
      "balance":1348,
      "dateCreated":"2020-06-30T08:09:53.259"
   },
   {
      "balance":1318,
      "dateCreated":"2020-06-30T06:43:08.339"
   },
   {
      "balance":1334,
      "dateCreated":"2020-06-30T06:42:51.645"
   }
]
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of error (where the graph/chart line/rect/path/circle is largely correct but with one or two errant points) can generally be traced to one of two issues:

- Errors in data
- Errors in parsing the data

In your case, the data is fine but your parsing of it does not account for an edge case, when your time does not have milliseconds, compare:

```js
const timeConv = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f");
console.log(timeConv("2020-07-19T04:50:29"));
console.log(timeConv("2020-07-19T04:52:21.601"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In your case, for one data point, d3.timeParse returns a null value in your case for one data point, causing a badly scaled x value for the path.

Two solutions come to mind, fix the data so this point is formatted as expected, or create a second time parser to account for this edge case:

```
.x((d) => xScale(timeConv(d.dateCreated) || timeConvEdgeCase(d.dateCreated)))
```

This seems hackier than ensuring consistently formatted data, but depending on your data source, this might need to be done inline or in loading the data in the browser anyways.

```js
const data=[{"balance":1433,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T19:03:38.627"},{"balance":1426,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T19:01:50.766"},{"balance":1449,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:58:56.856"},{"balance":1465,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:45:02.957"},{"balance":1476,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:38:27.707"},{"balance":1483,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:09:21.723"},{"balance":1489,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:07:10.662"},{"balance":1506,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T06:07:01.501"},{"balance":1515,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T04:06:49.871"},{"balance":1531,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T03:47:41.251"},{"balance":1542,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T03:04:08.571"},{"balance":1558,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:27:07.284"},{"balance":1575,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:21:03.609"},{"balance":1591,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:14:47.54"},{"balance":1596,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:13:51.064"},{"balance":1612,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T02:13:35.578"},{"balance":1620,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T01:49:01.64"},{"balance":1606,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T01:05:31.986"},{"balance":1639,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T00:13:31.93"},{"balance":1656,"dateCreated":"2020-07-23T00:05:29.045"},{"balance":1672,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T23:53:33.355"},{"balance":1679,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T23:45:19.324"},{"balance":1702,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T08:06:04.961"},{"balance":1709,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T07:41:31.159"},{"balance":949,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T06:11:06.519"},{"balance":915,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T04:11:45.495"},{"balance":932,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T03:31:21.528"},{"balance":981,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T02:09:29.896"},{"balance":965,"dateCreated":"2020-07-22T02:08:44.348"},{"balance":859,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T23:16:21.725"},{"balance":837,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T22:11:51.734"},{"balance":853,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T21:51:33.269"},{"balance":869,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T21:25:00.833"},{"balance":862,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T21:17:35.604"},{"balance":839,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T20:30:21.715"},{"balance":856,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T07:51:15.532"},{"balance":899,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T07:10:07.262"},{"balance":915,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T05:37:19.123"},{"balance":910,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T05:33:59.065"},{"balance":883,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T05:24:11.467"},{"balance":871,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T03:21:38.474"},{"balance":888,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T03:10:32.186"},{"balance":891,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T03:05:09.042"},{"balance":861,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T02:05:56.146"},{"balance":878,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T01:43:27.761"},{"balance":901,"dateCreated":"2020-07-21T01:34:25.554"},{"balance":907,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T23:18:39.558"},{"balance":924,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T22:59:25.504"},{"balance":940,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T21:01:51.96"},{"balance":879,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T20:48:54.406"},{"balance":857,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T19:56:13.648"},{"balance":890,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T19:50:26.716"},{"balance":906,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T19:00:18.921"},{"balance":882,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T07:46:33.574"},{"balance":896,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T07:07:40.55"},{"balance":879,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T07:04:25.858"},{"balance":906,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:52:07.748"},{"balance":922,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:42:51.575"},{"balance":927,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:42:31.973"},{"balance":934.26,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T06:16:09.036"},{"balance":902,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T05:31:56.692"},{"balance":923,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T05:31:47.108"},{"balance":894,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T05:22:20.871"},{"balance":867,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T04:00:32.576"},{"balance":883,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T04:00:26.06"},{"balance":900,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T02:14:11.529"},{"balance":916,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T01:38:55.908"},{"balance":933,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T01:23:53.772"},{"balance":949,"dateCreated":"2020-07-20T01:23:45.458"},{"balance":956,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:33:45.224"},{"balance":962,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:08:56.22"},{"balance":979,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:08:38.623"},{"balance":880,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T23:06:48.195"},{"balance":894,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T22:12:00.778"},{"balance":877,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:57:13.62"},{"balance":910,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:33:02.45"},{"balance":925,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:25:22.116"},{"balance":949,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T21:20:51.796"},{"balance":965,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T20:59:27.897"},{"balance":982,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T07:47:45.451"},{"balance":822,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T07:44:31.419"},{"balance":879,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T07:34:22.508"},{"balance":797,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:46:47.993"},{"balance":814,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:46:07.785"},{"balance":820,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:36:24.427"},{"balance":827,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:20:59.223"},{"balance":861,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:19:46.962"},{"balance":823,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:08:21.955"},{"balance":840,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:07:30.056"},{"balance":851,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T06:05:20.705"},{"balance":849,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:39:32.269"},{"balance":866.29,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:26:06.534"},{"balance":825,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:13:44.842"},{"balance":836,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:11:43.612"},{"balance":852,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:04:52.876"},{"balance":858,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:04:27.291"},{"balance":874.54,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T05:04:12.409"},{"balance":843,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:57:22.911"},{"balance":859,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:52:21.601"},{"balance":875.24,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:50:29"},{"balance":847,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:45:57.354"},{"balance":880,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:28:35.598"},{"balance":897,"dateCreated":"2020-07-19T04:17:26.469"},{"balance":913,"dateCreated":"2020-07-18T07:16:47.016"},{"balance":947,"dateCreated":"2020-07-18T06:37:00.094"},{"balance":930,"dateCreated":"2020-07-18T06:31:42.495"},{"balance":952,"dateCreated":"2020-07-17T09:08:22.177"},{"balance":939.94,"dateCreated":"2020-07-17T08:49:21.978"},{"balance":918,"dateCreated":"2020-07-17T08:34:31.417"},{"balance":929,"dateCreated":"2020-07-17T08:34:01.094"},{"balance":935,"dateCreated":"2020-07-16T07:08:20.004"},{"balance":951,"dateCreated":"2020-07-16T07:07:46.132"},{"balance":968,"dateCreated":"2020-07-14T04:39:32.887"},{"balance":984,"dateCreated":"2020-07-14T04:39:15.779"},{"balance":1000,"dateCreated":"2020-07-14T02:03:00.87"},{"balance":1017,"dateCreated":"2020-07-14T01:31:32.207"},{"balance":1033,"dateCreated":"2020-07-14T01:31:19.978"},{"balance":1040,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T23:23:29.921"},{"balance":1095.59,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T23:18:21.912"},{"balance":1072,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T22:37:24.883"},{"balance":1088,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T21:00:57.88"},{"balance":1091,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T20:10:58.344"},{"balance":1093.04,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T20:10:39.9"},{"balance":1055,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T19:20:51.553"},{"balance":1071,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T19:09:34.993"},{"balance":1071,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T19:09:12.291"},{"balance":1088.47,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T08:34:06.731"},{"balance":1020.97,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T08:24:09.093"},{"balance":999,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T08:12:13.226"},{"balance":1015,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T07:49:26.818"},{"balance":1032,"dateCreated":"2020-07-13T07:40:00.178"},{"balance":1114,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T23:23:32.335"},{"balance":1154,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T21:01:59.128"},{"balance":1169.97,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T14:39:57.463"},{"balance":1156,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T14:01:02.792"},{"balance":1172,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T13:55:36.566"},{"balance":1177,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T13:55:19.394"},{"balance":1156,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T08:24:33.968"},{"balance":1121,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T08:08:41.735"},{"balance":1089,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T06:48:28.84"},{"balance":1106,"dateCreated":"2020-07-12T05:40:55.865"},{"balance":1036,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T22:45:14.995"},{"balance":1012,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T21:52:56.498"},{"balance":1028,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T21:36:53.419"},{"balance":1043,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T09:20:19.116"},{"balance":1037,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:27:01.816"},{"balance":1043,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:26:45.696"},{"balance":1066,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:26:30.808"},{"balance":1070,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:08:32.191"},{"balance":1081.18,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T08:04:44.88"},{"balance":1049,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T06:59:57.157"},{"balance":1066,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T06:29:55.306"},{"balance":1082,"dateCreated":"2020-07-11T06:29:37.378"},{"balance":1089,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T07:20:38.373"},{"balance":1120,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T07:04:02.663"},{"balance":1131,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T07:02:00.364"},{"balance":1148,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T05:50:07.739"},{"balance":1164,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T05:24:33.478"},{"balance":1108,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T05:23:31.012"},{"balance":1083,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T04:10:02.153"},{"balance":1099,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T04:09:37.055"},{"balance":1114,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T02:40:05.837"},{"balance":1095,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T02:13:02.745"},{"balance":1106.16,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T02:10:33.916668"},{"balance":1108,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:43:12.406"},{"balance":1092,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:39:59.102"},{"balance":1113,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:35:38.467"},{"balance":1087,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T01:14:38.311"},{"balance":1103,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T00:50:09.294"},{"balance":1153,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T00:35:48.635"},{"balance":1136,"dateCreated":"2020-07-10T00:13:15.698"},{"balance":1169,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T23:42:45.742"},{"balance":1180,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T23:41:51.207"},{"balance":1186,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T20:29:33.056"},{"balance":1219,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T19:34:09.69"},{"balance":1235,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T19:18:24.581"},{"balance":1236,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T19:11:14.349"},{"balance":1252,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T17:13:40.924"},{"balance":1268,"dateCreated":"2020-07-09T06:47:22.183"},{"balance":1284,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T17:42:38.056"},{"balance":1301,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T17:42:28.833"},{"balance":1306.58,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:49:25.341"},{"balance":1285.58,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:32:08.722"},{"balance":1275,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:29:17.285"},{"balance":1282,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:29:09.891"},{"balance":1285,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:22:57.768"},{"balance":1290,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T08:20:55.432"},{"balance":1294,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T07:06:29.286"},{"balance":1300,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T06:47:13.151"},{"balance":1291,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T06:44:23.775"},{"balance":1270,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T05:46:22.013"},{"balance":1287,"dateCreated":"2020-07-08T05:45:47.899"},{"balance":1149,"dateCreated":"2020-07-07T11:19:38.463"},{"balance":1129.93,"dateCreated":"2020-07-07T08:29:41.744"},{"balance":1107,"dateCreated":"2020-07-07T07:48:21.005"},{"balance":1116,"dateCreated":"2020-07-07T07:48:04.45"},{"balance":1134,"dateCreated":"2020-07-07T06:07:27.17"},{"balance":1101,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T18:13:04.993"},{"balance":1075,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T16:50:49.551"},{"balance":1098,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T16:41:05.869"},{"balance":1105,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T04:53:57.638"},{"balance":1121,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T04:53:47.715"},{"balance":1128,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T03:52:28.386"},{"balance":1194,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T03:33:55.42"},{"balance":1177,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T03:19:55.119"},{"balance":1210,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:53:50.235"},{"balance":1227,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:40:53.788"},{"balance":1243,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:40:39.762"},{"balance":1252,"dateCreated":"2020-07-06T02:19:43.451"},{"balance":1269,"dateCreated":"2020-07-05T21:41:31.196"},{"balance":1275,"dateCreated":"2020-07-05T21:34:16.157"},{"balance":1219,"dateCreated":"2020-07-05T19:53:26.309"},{"balance":1192,"dateCreated":"2020-07-05T19:04:36.269"},{"balance":1198,"dateCreated":"2020-07-05T19:04:10.751"},{"balance":1249,"dateCreated":"2020-07-04T05:38:08.098"},{"balance":1228,"dateCreated":"2020-07-04T05:23:06.225"},{"balance":1271,"dateCreated":"2020-07-04T03:26:17.131"},{"balance":1304,"dateCreated":"2020-07-04T03:12:01.939"},{"balance":1327,"dateCreated":"2020-07-04T03:09:45.315"},{"balance":1334,"dateCreated":"2020-07-04T02:45:19.182"},{"balance":1343,"dateCreated":"2020-07-03T20:49:14.146"},{"balance":1353.8,"dateCreated":"2020-07-03T08:00:24.059"},{"balance":1290,"dateCreated":"2020-07-03T07:39:10.192"},{"balance":1322,"dateCreated":"2020-07-03T07:28:01.269"},{"balance":1322.65,"dateCreated":"2020-07-02T08:16:47.869"},{"balance":1287,"dateCreated":"2020-07-02T06:46:09.676"},{"balance":1304,"dateCreated":"2020-07-02T06:40:26.221"},{"balance":1310,"dateCreated":"2020-07-02T06:30:15.057"},{"balance":1328,"dateCreated":"2020-07-01T06:40:06.844"},{"balance":1345,"dateCreated":"2020-07-01T06:23:22.739"},{"balance":1348,"dateCreated":"2020-06-30T08:09:53.259"},{"balance":1318,"dateCreated":"2020-06-30T06:43:08.339"},{"balance":1334,"dateCreated":"2020-06-30T06:42:51.645"}]
const timeConv = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f");
const timeConvEdge = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
const width = 960;
const height = 500;
const margin = 5;
const padding = 5;
const adj = 30;

/* adding svg */
const svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
    .attr("viewBox", "-"
          + adj + " -"
          + adj + " "
          + (width + adj * 3) + " "
          + (height + adj * 3))
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .style("padding", padding)
    .style("margin", margin)

/* scaling */
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, d => timeConv(d.dateCreated) || timeConvEdge(d.dateCreated)));
    yScale.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, d => d.balance)
    ]);

    const yaxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .ticks(20)
        .scale(yScale);

    const xaxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(d => d3.timeDay.count(0, d) % 3 === 0))
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d'))
        .scale(xScale);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xaxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)")
        .call(yaxis);


    const line = d3.line()
        .x((d) => xScale(timeConv(d.dateCreated) || timeConvEdge(d.dateCreated)))
        .y((d) => yScale(d.balance));

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("stroke", "black")
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart">
```